shot=1 and reference sample in stim
I have seen relevant question and answer about"shot=1",I find the answer "Making a stim.TableauSimulator and running the circuit once is cheaper than compiling a sampler and taking only one shot",so I have the question——Is "shot=1" the same as the "reference sample" in terms of running speed?0r perhaps there is almost no difference between the two？or cheaper means quicker?

relevant question and answer about"shot=1"web


Is "shot=1" the same as the "reference sample" in terms of running speed?

The answer to this is complicated and may change.
First, note that the reference sample isn't created when you call sample. It's created when you call stim.Circuit.compile_sampler. So if you time sample(shots=1) it'll be way faster than stim.Circuit.reference_sample, because the reference sample is already cached.
Second, some optimizations are possible for the reference sample that would not be possible for a normal shot. In particular, when executing a loop, if the state of the system after iteration #2 is the same as it was after iteration #1, then the reference sample computation can simply copy paste the measurement results from the second iteration for all iterations. This would be a bug for a real sample, but for the reference sample it's fine because it can be any sample instead of needing to be a random sample.
This means, in principle, stim.Circuit.reference_sample can be enormously faster than sample(shots=1). Technically all that's required is for the circuit to have a REPEAT block with an enormous repetition count (like the million round memory experiment in the recent google 3v5v7 experiment). Stim does have code for doing this loop folding optimization for the reference sample, but it currently isn't used by the methods exposed to Python. Maybe in a future version it will.
Third, note that detection event sampling (stim.Circuit.compile_detector_sampler) never computes a reference sample at all.

understood,Thanks for the answer!
